# KSQLDB How Final Aggregation Happens with partitions?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Example i have topic with 4 partition and 2 instance ksqdb. As I understood from the documentation, each instance will take on two partitions.
Next i run query that `SUM ALL TICKET VALUES`, every instance calculate for self partitions but but where will the final aggregation(sum) of the last two values occur?

```
SELECT 
           SUM(TICKET_TOTAL_VALUE) AS TOTAL_VALUE
    FROM MOVIE_TICKET_SALES
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To clarify it's not guaranteed that 2 partitions will be assigned each node.

You also cannot easily get "last 2" events from a continuous query - the sum will be table/stream value for each unique ticket ID/key. In the case of a table, every unique key is stored together and aggregated.

Comment: 1) As far as I understood from the documentation ksqldb does auto-balance partitions in the same way as consumers do when connected to kafka if they are in the same groupID.  2) yes partition by FilmID but i calculate without GROUP 3) What do you mean I can't get it if I get the final 1 result in the console?

Comment: 1) Balancing is best-effort, not a guarantee. 2) You've not shown your `MOVIE_TICKET_SALES` stream, but the SUM implicitly does a group by on the stream key, I believe.  3) You can `EMIT CHANGES` or `PRINT` the result, but you're question seemed to be asking how to get the "last/most-recent 2 events", which isn't really possible without pre-aggregating events into groups of 2, then discarding all but the latest event.

Comment: The question is more about how it works, where what does what, who and how synchronizes the request. As a result, I want to understand how my query is paralleled in my scheme, where there is no grouping by keys, but absolutely all values from all sections are summed up

Comment: But there is grouping, as I mentioned. Ksql runs on servers you've installed it on, so I don't understand the question about "where/who". How - read Apache Kafka documentation on Kafka Streams and stateful processing. A consumer group is created, and it's distributed (not necessarily balanced) over each instance, then each consumer reads its assigned partitions and builds a local state store with the sum value, for each key (therefore a grouping). Those results are unified in a driver to present the sum of all partitions in a ksqlDB table/stream output